# how to preview image before upload in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i am trying to upload and preview image using jquery. But getting this

**Error**

```
Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
reader.onload = function (e) {
 $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
```

**page.ts**

```
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}


$('#file').on('change', function () {
  readURL(this);
});
```

**page.html**

```
 <label for="file" class="lbl"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> &nbsp; Add Attachment</label>
<input type="file" id="file" style="visibility: hidden">
<img src="#" id="blah">
```

what will be the solution?? i think this code is correct but just the problem is 'result' property. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us your exact requirement? You cannot use `jQuery` with `Ionic 3`.

Comment: just preview the image when selected.. but for your kind information i have installed and import 'JQUERY' already.

Comment: Do you need this kind of behavior? http://oidamo.de/angular2-image-gallery/

Comment: No, just want to show image on screen when select from Gallery before upload

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some time ago, I used the following code to preview an image in Ionic.

In HTML:

```html
<input type="file" value="" (change)="fileChange($event)">
<img *ngIf="img1" [src]="img1"/>
```

In JavaScript:

```js
fileChange(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event:any) => {
      this.img1 = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);  // to trigger onload
  }
  
  let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;  
  let file: File = fileList[0];
  console.log(file);
}
```

Improvements are welcome

Comment: add " img1:any; " before constructor and after export class

Answer (score 2):

for ionic 4

In html

```
        <img class="logo" src="{{img_new}}" *ngIf="img_new!=''"/>

        <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" (change)="changeListener($event)">
```

In ts

```
changeListener($event): void {
        this.file = $event.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.file);
    let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = ($event:any) => {
        this.img_new = $event.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL($event.target.files[0]);
    }
```